# Dynamically add class member using string to name it

Tags: python, class, dynamic, member

In Python, I'm quite aware of the fact that one may add members to classes after their definition. But, is there a way to name a member using the content of a string?

For example, I may do this:

```
class A:
    pass
A.foo = 10

a = A()
print a.foo
```

But is there some way to do this:

```
name = "foo"
class A:
    pass
A.[some trick here(name)] = 10

a = A()
print a.foo
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `setattr`:

```
setattr(A, 'foo', 10)
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes! This can be done with a combination of [getattr](https://web.archive.org/web/20200703234823/http://effbot.org/zone/python-getattr.htm) and [setattr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=setattr#setattr).

```
setattr(A, 'foo', 10)
getattr(A, 'foo') // Returns 10
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI - you can generate a dict from the members of an entire object using `vars()`:

```
class A:
    pass
A.foo = 10
A.bar = 'hello'

a = A()
b = vars(a)
print(b['bar'])  # prints hello
```